# Why I still get the x86-64 .so file, althrough using the ./configure -- host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf?

Tags: c, linux, arm, libmodbus

I want to using libmodbus on PICO whhich is ARM. I'm using a x86-64 ubuntu PC.
Is that right to use `./configure -- host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf ?`  and `make`,`make install`. No errors after these 3 steps. but I checked /usr/local/lib/, But the libmodbus.so.5.1.0 is x86-64. and pico-sdk can't recoganize this format.

Comment: Why space between `--` and `host`?

Comment: Also `make install` for shared libraries of foreign architecture is not a good idea, as well as for native libraries. Use `make DESTDIR=<some dir in your project> install`.